# Django test case loop for all url_patterns for anonymous users

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-testing

My webapp requires a login, and I want to test that all url_patterns in a django app, `badges`, redirect to the login/home page.

I have a loop here that can handle simple urls:

```
class ViewTests(TestCase):

    def test_all_badge_page_status_codes_for_anonymous(self):
        ''' If not logged in then all views should redirect to home page '''
        for path in urlpatterns:
            name = 'badges:%s' % path.name
            self.assertRedirects(
                response=self.client.get(reverse(name)),
                expected_url='%s?next=%s' % (reverse('home'), reverse(name)),
            )
```

However, this fails for any path that requires a keyword argument, such as:

`path('<int:badge_id>', views.detail, name='badge_detail'),`

How can I automagically, insert arguments for paths so I don't have to write a separate line for each `path` in `url_patterns`?

Comment: Add the [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator?

Comment: They all have that.  Not sure how that helps my tests?